# Why use specific exception catch blocks

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

In the code below, I have a catch block for `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException` class exception.

My question is that why I can't use `Exception` class to catch each and every possible exception in my code and get stacktrace?

What is the advantage of specific exception types and their use in multiple catch blocks?

```
try
{
    AddAdminUserInput input1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddAdminUserInput>(input);
    Foundation_Services_DL_DataEntities Db = DLMetadataContext.GetContext();
    UserAccount account = new UserAccount
    {
        emplid = input1.emplid,
        sso = input1.sso,
        deptid = input1.deptid,
        usertype = input1.usertype,
        status = input1.status,
        username = input1.username
    };

    Db.UserAccounts.Add(account);
    Db.SaveChanges();

    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dict.Add("status", "0");
    dict.Add("message", "User Addition Successful");

    Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict));
}
catch (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException dbev)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dict.Add("status", "1");
    dict.Add("message", "User Addition Failed - User Already Exists");

    Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict));
}
```

Comment: `My question is that why i can't use Exception class to catch each and every possible exception in my code?` If you did that, how would you give  different `status` codes for different exceptions as you do in your above code?

Comment: The answer to your question is that you can use `Exception` to catch all problems. You will have a headache identifying and fixing problems when you run into one if you don't use specifics to narrow the location of the problem.

Comment: This is a legitimate and answerable question- I don't understand the close voting, unless it's a dupe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is the advantage of specific Exception types and their use in multiple catch blocks?

A better way to ask the same question is "what is a disadvantage of catching less specific Exception types." The answer to this question is very straightforward: you could inadvertently catch an exception that you do not know how to handle.

As a rule, the code should catch an Exception only when it knows what to do with it, e.g. report an error, retry with a counter, ask end-user for a decision on how to proceed, and so on. This is possible only when you limit the exceptions that you catch to a specific group, such as `DbUpdateException`.

A nice "bonus" for catching specific exceptions is that you get access to properties and methods defined only on the specific subclasses. For example, `DbUpdateException` tells you which entries failed to save through [`Entries`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateexception.entries(v=vs.113).aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException.Entries) property, which gives you an opportunity to attempt a retry.

Finally, certain exceptions are meant to be caught only at the top-level of your program. These exceptions indicate programming errors - for example, accessing a `null` reference, accessing an array past the end or at a negative index, dividing by zero, and so on. There is nothing your program could do to recover from these errors, because fixing them requires a code change. Therefore, the only thing the program could do is to log or otherwise report the exception before exiting or initiating a restart sequence.

Comment: +1 - sometimes it is useful to catch any exceptions and handle them, but especially in utility functions, it is better to catch only a subset of "expected" exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you from catching Exception but it is not advised unless you just want to simply log the exception and rethrow it.

Catching specific exceptions allows you to handle specific scenarios that you know how to fix.

There's some pretty good information on exceptions, how they behave and how best to handle them here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a catch all exception but if there are specific exceptions that you want to handle differently, it can be useful to cater for them individually. In your example you're adding to a dictionary that can then provide some useful feedback rather than crashing. You wouldn't be able to do that for a catch all block.

An example from some code I've worked with:

```
catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException comException)
{
    // Logout has already occurred
    this.VerboseLog($"Disconnect not required. ERROR LOGGED BUT WILL BE IGNORED; {comException}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   this.ErrorLog(ex);
   throw;
}
```

In this first catch the error is not really a problem; it's being logged but it can carry on running. In the second catch the error is a problem it's being written to a log but it's not going to be handled further as we don't know what it is or what to do with it.

Comment: This isn't really a good answer- not that it's wrong, but it doesn't offer much. Consider adding examples and additional rationale. Look at some of the other answers to see what a good answer might look like.

Comment: That's fair - I've just been hunting through my code to find an example, not actually the easiest thing to search for mind

Comment: You should never do `throw ex;` where `ex` is a caught exception. You lose your stack trace. Just do `throw;`.

Comment: Better it looks now